# Capture messages sent to Azure Service Bus Topics with no subscriptions or filtered out?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to create a Service Bus Topic with a couple of subscriptions using filters for different message types. However I need to guarantee that all messages sent to the Topic will be received and successfully processed by at least one subscription, even if all of the subscribing processes go offline.

Is there a better way than auto-forwarding to queues for each filter, and a way to capture messages ignored by all filtering subscribers without capturing all messages?

Edit: my motivation is to provide a queue-like mechanism with prioritisation without creating a queue for each message type/priority level, or at least manage the complexity of multiple queues on the listening side. A queue generally guarantees a consumer. Rather than have the publisher have to push to different queues I would like to use a topic and use filters to manage priority.

Based on my current knowledge of the SB I suspect that I just need to make sure the subscriptions are in place for a topic including an inverse catch-all filter subscription before exposing the topic for use. I don't know whether subscriptions are completely reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I need to guarantee that all messages sent to the Topic will be received and successfully processed by at least one subscription, even if all of the subscribing processes go offline.

There's a problem in that statement. Topics and subscriptions are there to implement pub/sub and decouple publishers from subscribers. The broker itself does not guarantee there will be subscribers.

While topics support `EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` ([`TopicDescription.EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.enablefilteringmessagesbeforepublishing?view=azure-dotnet)) it is **not** recommended for production use.

**Update**

Based on the updated question, the general answer remains the same. Topics/subscriptions are for pub/sub and decoupling. If you want to ensure that no message is lost once subscriber is coming online, you will need to ensure that subscription is created first.

> I don't know whether subscriptions are completely reliable.

Yes, subscriptions are reliable. Behind the scenes subscription is a queue.

In case you want to route your messages to different processors based on message type, publishing that message to a topic and having forwarding subscriptions is a good approach. You do need to be mindful of the [quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) (how many subscriptions per topic you can create), but those are fairly high. And if you get to that point, it's possible to reduce number of subscriptions when a given processor handles multiple message types by having more complex [SQL filtering rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter).

Comment: I'll update my answer, but the general idea remains the same.